# How do I get rid of this white frame with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap with a project I'm working on at the moment and I'm seeing a white border appear around the main header and footer when I make the screen a little narrower.

You can see the same problem on [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) which also uses Bootstrap - just make the screen a little narrower and you'll see a white box appearing on the right side of the screen at the header and footer.

Anybody know what's causing it?!

Comment: Font Awesome => no white border in Opera, Firefox, Safari & Chrome.

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: I see this in Safari 6 on Mac, Firefox 18 on Mac and Chrome 24 on Mac. Safari on iPhone and Safari on iPad

Comment: To re-create the error, drag the window so it's narrower, about 500 px, and then scroll to the far right. You should see white boxes appearing in the header and footer